# Should I include refeeding after 48h fasts while in maintenance phase?

Tags: calories, intermittent-fasting, maintenance

I've been training in the gym for several years and decided to go on a longer maintenance phase, as I am really happy with my current body composition. I've been in maintenance for over half a year by now. I eat around 2700 kcal per day on average and train 3-5 times a week, depending on my schedule. My weight and body composition is constant.

Following the current health recommendations, I want to include 48h fasts twice a month in my protocol. If I do not compensate for the 5400 kcal missing per fast, I will miss those calories over time. Should I increase my average calories on eating days to compensate for this delta or is there a better way to refeed? Is refeeding even necessary in this scenario? My goal is still keeping my weight and body composition constant.

Comment: Who's recommending a 48h fast?

Comment: Researchers in the field of healthy aging (e.g. Dr. Peter Attia and Dr. Rhonda Patrick). The idea behind the 48h fast is to reap the most benefits of autophagy while not affecting muscle mass. There are different protocols, but 48h is a good middle ground, as long as you do not do it more often than once or twice a month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

48 hour fasts or prolonged fasting is awesome when it comes to increasing autophagy, increasing HGH, entering ketosis, curbing your hunger, refreshing your body and mind, spiritually, etc.

If your goal is to maintain body composition then the 48H fasts will allow you some wiggle room with your calories. Post 48H fast, definitely refeed. If you're low-carb normally stick with it during your refeed. If you're high-carb normally, you will have just entered Ketosis at around 36 hours. If you're miserable, that's probably why.

Also be sure to drink your "snake juice" during the fast to provide your body with proper electrolytes.

When it comes to the caloric wiggle room, and eating more to compensate, that sounds like a good idea based on your goal of maintenance. Just don't go overboard, post-fast refeeds can feel ravenous, but your eyes will be bigger than your stomach.

When you say you will "miss" those calories over time, it's a logical fallacy. You will not "miss" the calories, you will simply be in a caloric deficit, which is surmountable with a cheat day or just stay in the deficit. You won't "miss" it anymore after refeed and it will keep you at maintenance with less effort over time.